# Promise, Async Await

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, es6-promise

```
setDeviceTimeout = id => timeout => {
    const {onSetDevices, devices} = this.props;

    var newDeviceList = devices.map(device => {
        if (device.id === id) {
            var newDevice = {
                //...device,
                timeout: timeout
            };
            deviceTable.oncePostDevice(newDevice).then( data => {
                return newDevice = data
            });
        }
        return device;
    });

    onSetDevices(newDeviceList);
}
```

So the issue I am having here is that the `onSetDevices(newDeviceList)` get's called before the `devices.map()` is finished. This is because the `devices.map()` has the call to a server `oncePostDevice(newDevice)`, then returns the data and stores it in the `newDevice` variable and puts that into the `newDeviceList` array.

Because this happens `onSetDevices` doesn't include the the `newDevice` in the `newDeviceList` array of objects and when I set my redux state using `onSetDevices`, nothing has changed.

I am wondering how I turn this into an *async*, *await* or use a *promise* alone to finish the task of making `onSetDevices` wait for the `devices.map()` to finish.

Also here is the code for `oncePostDevice`:

```
export const oncePostDevice = (device) => new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    fetch('https://url/devices/'+device.id, {
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(device)
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(
        data => {return resolve(data)},
        error => {return reject(error)}
    )
    .catch(err => console.error(this.props.url, err.toString()));
});
```

As you can see I already have a *promise* in here working and returning the data afterwards.

I just need to know how to make my `setDeviceTimeout` inner mapping function finish before I hit `onSetDevices`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you could do it (explanations inline in code):

```
// make the function async
setDeviceTimeout = id => async timeout => {
  const {onSetDevices, devices} = this.props;

  // make a list of promises, not of devices
  // note: mapping a value via an async function will create promises
  const newDeviceListPromises = devices.map(async device => {
    if (device.id === id) {
      const newDevice = {
        ...device,
        timeout: timeout
      };
      return await deviceTable.oncePostDevice(newDevice);
    }
    return device;
  });

  // wait for all promises to finish and what they return will be the devices
  const newDeviceList = await Promise.all(newDeviceListPromises);

  onSetDevices(newDeviceList);
};
```

Comment: Perfect!!! Thank you sir! This worked like a charm, I really cannot thank you enough, I have been wracking my brain trying to solve this.